# Nest.js - How to pass parameters to a provider's constructor using DI?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I've a dedicated service class for instantiating Puppeteer and to get a page instance. Also, based on `useProxy` property I need to use a Puppeteer extra plugin which uses proxy to process the request. How I can pass this value in another service class using DI mechanism?

In puppeteer service:

```
@Injectable()
export class PuppeteerService {
   public constructor(
    public useProxy?: boolean
  ) {
    if(this.useProxy) {
     // use proxy plugin
    }
  }
}
```

In another service class:

```
@Injectable()
export class WebScrapingService {
   // A way to pass the param here
   public constructor(private readonly puppeteerService: PuppeteerService) 
   { }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Actually, I don't have an idea how to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `puppeteerService.useProxy`?.Does it exists?

Comment: Nest.js throws this error when try to start the dev server: ` Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PuppeteerService (ConfigService, ?). Please make sure that the argument Boolean at index [1] is available in the PuppeteerModule context.
`